# Windows-Phone-7 Missing Libraries

Tags: windows-phone-7

Just a quick question.

I have noticed that there are some missing things to the .NET framework in windows-phone-7.  For instance, the library "System.Servicemodel.Syndication".

Is there a reason for this? And is there an easy way to get it back?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WP7 exposes 
- a subset of the .net framework 
- a sub/superset of the silverlight 3 framework as is suitable for the phone
- and xna

These doucments cover the specifics of what is available and what is different at this stage of the SDK's development.

[Features Supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931(v=VS.95).aspx)

[Differences Between Silverlight on Windows Phone and Silverlight on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930(v=VS.95).aspx)

[Class Library Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470087(v=VS.95).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No. Win phone 7 is based on silverlight which is a subset of the full .net framework.

Comment: there's no way i can import them via DLL or something?

Comment: There is a Silverlight 3 version of this in the Silverlight 3 Toolkit, although I have not tried it personally yet the Silverlight 3 Syndication DLL for RSS feeds etc should work.
Windows Phone 7 is based on Silverlight 3 so most Silverlight 3 DLLs that use something the phone supports should work.